# How to sort data in a struct array using qsort (C)

Tags: c, struct, quicksort

I have a struct array (each element is a row) that has a float (each element is a column). How would I sort this by column assuming that the table has been fully initalized.. how would I go about sorting by floats using qsort(). I am completely stuck. My code:

```
typedef struct row
{   
    float value[20];
}ROW;

//in the main function I initalize ROW table[100]

my qsort call: 
qsort(table, row, sizeof(*table), &compare);


my compare function:

int compare(const void* first, const void *second)
{
    float firstTotal = (*(ROW **)first)->value;
    float secondTotal = (*(ROW **)second)->value;

    return firstTotal - secondTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort elements within each struct, then your qsort call will operate on the array of floats.

```
qsort(((ROW*)->value), 20, sizeof(float), comparefloats);
```

Then the comparison is just between two floats.

```
int comparefloats(const void *left, const void *right) {
    float lt = *(float *)left;
    float rt = *(float *)right;
    return (fabs(lt - rt) < 0.0001)? 0:
                              lt - rt > 0? 1: -1;
}
```

Sorting the rows themselves, if there's a larger array of them, will involve a less-straightforward notion of comparing two arrays.

As you say, you want to sort "by columns", in that case, unfortunately `qsort` is not your friend. It's not a *stable* sort, you see. So you can't just sort row by row in increasing order of priority.

To sort columns, one at a time (or sequentially, if you find a stable-sort with the same interface),
you'll need a different comparison function for each column, or a comparison with different behavior each time it's called. The obvious way would be with a global variable.

```
int column_to_compare;
int comparefloatcolumn(const void *left, const void *right) {
    float lt = (*(ROW *)left).value[ column_to_compare ];
    float rt = (*(ROW *)right).value[ column_to_compare ];
    return (fabs(lt - rt) < 0.0001)? 0:
                              lt - rt > 0? 1: -1;
}
```

Then you need to set the column before each call to qsort.

```
column_to_compare = 0;
qsort(rowarray, 100, sizeof(ROW), comparefloatcolumn);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it clear. If you read the comment You'll see that I said that in the main function I initalized ROW table[100]. I have a struct array with a float array in it.

Comment: Ok. I see it now. It'd be easier to see in code. I'd edit to address that.

Comment: I still don't understand why you are doing fabs but I can figure that part out. The program works. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The fabs part is to deal with the notion of nearly-equal. If the difference is smaller than some very small amount, the two values are considered equal. Very often floating point calculations will yield values like 2.9999999999 when it should be 3.0. This way of doing it will yield results closer to your real-world expectations. The "very small" value to use will depend on the datatype. For float, 5 or 6 zeros should work, for double, more like 10 or 11.

Comment: O okay, yes I understand now. I learned about floating point representation last week. Thanks again.